# Calculation of Bond/Angle/Dihedral force constant

Tags: computational-chemistry, transition-metals

I am a big fan of Mopac (Though I have a very little knowledge about the tool). I have some queries regarding some calculations in Mopac2016:

Problem:

How to calculate Bond or Angle or Dihedral force constant for Vanadium (V) (with other elements: Oxygen and Chlorine)?

My compound (smiliar to): CN(OV(=O)ON(C)C(C)=O)C(C)=O

Structure: [image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question correctly: Do you wish to calculate a force constant using a method *in* Mopac, such as PM7?

Comment: yes. I need the method to calculate the force constants using Mopac2016.

Comment: It should be possible to perform a "FORCE" calculation, visualize the resulting vibrational modes and extract the force constant from the appropriate frequency. Note that you need a well-converged geometry for this, preferably without negative frequencies.

Comment: [1] and [2] provide you with two CIF files (all distances and angles are present) of chloro-oxo-bis(N-phenylbenzylhydroxamato-O,O')-vanadium(V), replace phenyl groups with protons and you have perfect starting geometry. 


  [1]: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cber.19891220205/abstract
  [2]: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1381116904002961

Comment: @TAR86 : Thank you. And force did work , please write as an answer and I will close this question. *But it gives back result in a weird way?* How to interpret it? example: http://openmopac.net/manual/Formaldehyde_output.htmlstion

Comment: Finally found it! SEMINAR10, JORGE M. "Calculation of intramolecular force fields from second-derivative tensors." (1996). http://compbio.chemistry.uq.edu.au/mediawiki/upload/2/2a/Seminario_Hess2FF.pdf

Comment: @DevashishDas You can also answer your own question, and this can potentially help others in the future.